# Twitter typeahead.js breaks when cloned with jQuery clone() [fiddle inside]

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

I have been integrating Twitter typeahead.js (version 0.9.2) into a project of mine with great success, but I ran into a problem the other day on a page that uses jQuery's [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method to insert and remove form controls.

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AzSgy/8/) showing what I mean. Try typing 'o' or 't' into the existing element, then adding a new one with the '+' or '>>' buttons. If you then click on the newly created typeahead, you can see that it opens the suggestions menu for the one above it, and otherwise doesn't act like a typeahead at all.

---

Here's part of the fiddle since SO won't let me post just a link:

#### HTML Dom structure surrounding typeahead

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">
    <form>
        <input name="example" /> <!-- initialized as typeahead -->
        <button type="button" class="addBlock">+</button>
        <!-- other buttons omitted -->
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

#### jQuery driver code for '+' button

```
$(document).on('click', '.addBlock', function(){
    var clone = $(this).parents('.inner').clone(true, true);
    clone.appendTo($('div.outer'));
});
```

Comment: I don't understand the addition of the 'fiddler' tag. Doesn't that refer to [Fiddler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiddler_(software))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are only calling the typeahead function when the page is ready. The element that you're creating doesn't exist at device ready so typeahead isn't getting assigned to it. you have to call typeahead every time that you add a new one.

Comment: That fixes part, but not all of it. See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AzSgy/9/). The bottom one behaves like a typeahead now when you add with the '+' button (the only one I fixed), but it still opens the suggestions on the wrong one if you've already typed in the first one.

Comment: Actually the more I play with it the more I realize this fixes all but one issue -- the edge case where one is cloned while the suggestion box is up. Doing it this way (see Fiddle) worked much better than my original attempt using $(document).on(), so I'm going to go ahead and mark yours accepted!

Comment: One final note: To get the whole solution in place I actually had to call .typeahead('destroy'), THEN clone, then re-init typeahead. The 'destroy' call removes all the extra DOM elements, and failing to do this step results in some very odd markup indeed!

Comment: That's good to know. I didn't even think of calling destroy to fix it. I'm glad I could help though!